# git remove commits in a new branch which was accidently created from branch other than master

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I created a new branch from master and named it 'LoginFeature'. I completed all the work in this branch and then pushed it back to LoginFeature. Then I created a new branch 'Dashboard' from 'LoginFeature' and merged Master into 'Dashboard'. I added few code files in 'Dashboard' and pushed them to my 'Dashboard' branch on server.

Next day, I realized that I should have created 'Dashboard' from 'Master' instead of 'LoginFeature'.

How can I fix this? Can I remove all the commits of 'LoginFeature' branch from 'Dashboard' branch. Or should I delete 'Dashboard' branch from local and remote and recreate 'Dashboard' branch from master and copy paste my new files in to this branch?

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the `Dashboard` branch and recreate it from `Master` branch. Add all files again and push them.
2. You can change the parent for the branch `Dashboard`. Since commit SHAs involve their parents, when you change the parent of a given commit, its SHA will change and it will create confusion for other users. For this you have to use `rebase`:

```
git rebase --onto `new_parent` `old_parent`
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a branch diagram:

```
master:        A -- B -- C
                     \
LoginFeature:         D -- E
                            \
Dashboard:                   F -- G
```

You want to obtain this structure:

```
LoginFeature:         D -- E
                     /
master:        A -- B -- C
                          \
Dashboard:                 F' -- G'
```

We can try using `git rebase --onto` here:

```
# from your Dashboard branch
git checkout Dashboard
git rebase --onto C E
```

This says to rebase the `Dashboard` branch by rewriting history such that the commit whose parent is `E` (which is `F` in the above diagram) now sits on a new commit/base of `C`.  Here `C` is the latest commit on the `master` branch.

Note that I labelled the `F'` and `G'` commits *after* the rebase with dashes.  This is to indicate that these commits are actually completely *new* commits.  Rebasing commits generally means rewriting them.

Also, your actual `Dashboard` branch has a merge commit coming from `master`.  But, rebase by default will ignore merge commits, so this should be dropped during to rebase onto process.